# How to create interactive/collapeable/expandable, like trees in Django?

Tags: jquery, django

jQuery has a plugin called [JSTree](http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/), which creates an interactive tree.  I would like to create an interactive tree in Django as well. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's role in this would be creating, saving, and modifying data, not providing the interface or interpretation of that data. Maybe a good start would be to model tree structures using  the Django ORM:

```
TreeNode(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("TreeNode", null=True, blank=True)

    # all your various tree data goes here...
    description = models.TextField(help_text="notes about my node!")
```

Django's other role would be creating a view that can save and load this data, and then render a template that in turn uses jQuery plugins such as the one you mentioned to present a nice interface for editing the data.

So, to create a simple tree structure, you could do something like, in a Django view:

```
tree_parent = TreeNode.objects.create()
tree_child_1 = TreeNode.objects.create(parent=tree_parent, description="Leaf 1")
tree_child_2 = TreeNode.objects.create(parent=tree_parent, description="Another leaf...")
```

Now, without knowing anything more about your requirements, this is about all I can give. However, in most applications, you'll probably want a "Tree" model also, that all nodes reference, to associate all related nodes, so you don't have to recurse and make many database calls.